# Как послать сообщение с сервера на клиента WebSocket в Django?

Tags: python, django, websocket

Использую Channels для реализации вебсокета. Нужно, чтобы при выполнении какой-то функции я мог отправить на клиента по веб-сокету сообщение (типа уведомления). Как реализовать данный процесс?

Comment: Как описано в документации Channels. Что у вас конкретно не получилось?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev какой вопрос - такой и ответ. Человек сам себе рейтинг накручивает только ему понятными вопросами.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Я не накручиваю рейтинг. Вам наверное делать нечего, раз вы ходите по уже закрытым вопросам и пишите такие комментарии. У меня стояла задача - определенной группе лиц отправлять определенные уведомления с помощью Channels. Подключение к сокету я осуществить смог, но с отправкой данных много парился, пока на одном форуме человек не показал пример своего проекта. И думаю другим будет неплохо сразу находить ответ на похожий вопрос, а не слушать "Читать документацию" или "Накручивают рейтинг". Мне на стаке нужны ответы на мои вопросы, а не цифры.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич И кстати - рейтинг не зачисляется за свои ответы, за свои вопросы. К чему тогда ваше сообщение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос:

```
Group("notify").send({
            "text": json.dumps({
                "type": 'task',
                "id": data['doer_id'],
                "task_id": task_id,
                "content": data['description']
            })
        })
```

в Group указываем нужный нам канал и отправляет объект со свойством text, куда кидаем наши данные.